# cast to void**, for what reason?

Tags: c, pointers, casting

here is C code from the book "The C programming language":

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h> 

#define MAXLINES 5000    /* max #lines to be sorted */
char *lineptr[MAXLINES]; /* pointers to text lines */

int readlines(char *lineptr[], int nlines);
void writelines(char *lineptr[], int nlines);

void qsort(void *lineptr[], int left, int right, 
        int (*comp)(void *, void *));

int numcmp(char *, char *);

/* sort input lines */
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int nlines;

    int numeric = 0; /* number of input lines read */

    if (argc > 1 && strcmp(argv[1], "-n") == 0)  /* 1 if numeric sort */
        numeric = 1;
    if ((nlines = readlines(lineptr, MAXLINES)) >= 0) {
        qsort((void**) lineptr, 0, nlines-1, // MY QUESTION: WHY lineptr IS CAST TO POINTER TO A VOID POINTER
                (int (*)(void*,void*))(numeric ? numcmp : strcmp));
        writelines(lineptr, nlines);
        return 0;
    } else {
        printf("input too big to sort\n");
        return 1;
    }
}


void qsort(void *v[], int left, int right,
        int (*comp)(void *, void *))
{
    int i, last;
    void swap(void *v[], int, int);
    // rest of code
}
```

Why when qsort function is called first argument is being cast to pointer to a void pointer (void **) and not just to pointer to void (void *) . Please tell me why is it so?

Thanks

Comment: That's the type of argument `qsort` expects. When you pass `lineptr`, that would become a `char**` and the compiler should complain. Casting the pointer to the expected type shuts up the compiler because it says "I know what I'm doing" and converts the argument to the correct type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compilers will warn you these days unless you cast non-void pointers to void pointers when you pass them as void pointers (if that made any sense). I think you knew that, though.

The signature of `void **lineptr` is equivalent in C to `void *lineptr[]`, which is the type of pointer that `qsort` takes as an argument. See [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_signature) site for more details.

Comment: hi, thanks! I didn't see the equivalence at first. I see it well now.

Answer (score 0):

Here, the`qsort` function defines an `int (*comp)(void *, void *)` parameter and `*comp` is a function pointer that can be used to call a function of the comparison. Even they don't have the same function name (`comp` and `numcmp`), it's still valid.

Comment: Hey@XB.Wang please avoide the answer on the old post give on the new post..